# Angular components not served after updating JHipster, only serves root index.html

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I was trying to update my Jhipster 4.0 project (which used Angular 4) to Jhipster 6.0 (which used Angular 9). There was such a difference in the Angular version and Typescript version, that I instead just created a Jhipster 6.0 project, and then I replaced all of the following files in this Jhipster 6.0 project. These files were replaced with the files from the Jhipster 4.0 project, so I could get the front-end working again - src/main/webapp - src/test - package.json - webpack - tsconfig.json

In essence this makes it use angular 4 again ... makes it use the old typescript ... and lets it have all of the old front-end code. I can bring the application app just fine (using ./mvnw and npm start). But only http://localhost:9061

I'm attempting to serve the old angular code through port 8080. Currently only the index.html file gets served there, and it is the nearly empty html file with a jhipster needle. 
When I attempt other url paths, this page is still served up.
For example, the following urls both serve up the root index.html file:

- http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard
- http://localhost:8080/app/dashboard

But, if I try to serve up static content from similar urls, that does work. For example, this does return the .css file correctly:

- http://localhost:8080/app/dashboard/dashboard.css

So, in short, I'm trying to find a way to serve up slightly older Angular (v4) from an updated JHipster app, but the angular components are not being served. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have this in your webpack.dev.js - `contentBase: './target/classes/static',` ... and that you do NOT have this - `contentBase: './target/www',`

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the paths changed between versions of JHipster. This works.